# LISTAGG fails in subquery (ORA-01489)

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, listagg

I'm using LISTAGG successfully in a query by itself, however I want to bring it in to a larger query.  I have created a subquery in the FROM and am using that to reference the LISTAGG but I then get the ORA-01489 even though the length was fine when it wasn't in a subquery.  I just don't see why putting the LISTAGG in a subquery causes it to suddenly break the 4000char limit?

So the below works fine by itself...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
PERSON.PIN "ContactRef",
LISTAGG(CODE.DESCR, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CODE.DESCR) "Considerations2"

FROM
PERSON,
PERSON_SECURE_INFO,
CODE

WHERE
PERSON.PIN = PERSON_SECURE_INFO.PIN (+)
AND CODE.CODE = PERSON_SECURE_INFO.PSI_CODE
AND (CODE.CODE_TYPE = 'PSI' OR CODE.CODE_TYPE IS NULL)
AND PERSON_SECURE_INFO.PIN is not null

GROUP BY PERSON.PIN
```

But when I include that in my larger SQL block, I get the ORA error.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
PERSON.PIN "ContactRef",
PERSON.TITLE "Salutation",
PERSON.FORENAME "Forename",
PERSON.PERSON_SURNAME "Surname",
PERSON.HOME_TEL_NUM "Contact1",
'1' "Contact1Type" /*Home Phone*/,
PERSON.MOBILE_TEL_NUM "Contact2",
'5' "Contact2Type" /*Mobile Phone*/,
PERSON.EMAIL_ADDRESS "Contact3",
'6' "Contact3Type" /*Email*/,
null "Contact4",
null "Contact4Type",
'2' "PreferredContact",
CODE.DESCR "Considerations",
LISTAGG(CODEPSI.DESCR, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CODEPSI.DESCR) "Considerations2"

FROM
PERSON,
RNT_OCCUPANTS,
CODE,
 (SELECT DISTINCT
PERSON.PIN "ContactRef",
CODE.DESCR
FROM
PERSON,
PERSON_SECURE_INFO,
CODE
WHERE
PERSON.PIN = PERSON_SECURE_INFO.PIN (+)
AND CODE.CODE = PERSON_SECURE_INFO.PSI_CODE
AND (CODE.CODE_TYPE = 'PSI' OR CODE.CODE_TYPE IS NULL)
AND PERSON_SECURE_INFO.PIN is not null) "CODEPSI"    

WHERE
PERSON.PIN = RNT_OCCUPANTS.PIN
AND PERSON.WARNING_CODE = CODE.CODE (+)
AND (CODE.CODE_TYPE = 'WARN' OR CODE.CODE_TYPE IS NULL)
AND RNT_OCCUPANTS.PARTY = 'Y'
AND RNT_OCCUPANTS.END_DATE_OF_OCCUPANCY is null

GROUP BY
PERSON.PIN,
PERSON.TITLE,
PERSON.FORENAME,
PERSON.PERSON_SURNAME,
PERSON.HOME_TEL_NUM,
PERSON.MOBILE_TEL_NUM,
PERSON.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
CODE.DESCR
```

Can anyone offer some advice? Thanks

Comment: Are you getting duplicate entries now because of the extra joins?

Comment: Ahh darnit....I started to go through the joins to see where that might happen and noticed that I'd missed out joining the subquery table back to the original PERSON table.

 I've added in the join PERSON.PIN = CODEPSI.PIN and now it works

Comment: You might find it easier to avoid things like that if you use ANSI JOIN syntax rather than the old syntax; particularly with outer joins.